# Table join with entity (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony and am having trouble getting my entities set up. I want to be able to access the tag names from my Acasset entity.

Here are the relevant entities:

```
class Actag
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag_name", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tagName;  

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $tagId;



/**
 * Acassettag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acAssetTag", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_7C4A2A745DA1941", columns={"asset_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_7C4A2A74BAD26311", columns={"tag_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Acassettag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\Acasset
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Acasset", inversedBy="asset", cascade="PERSIST")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="asset_id", referencedColumnName="asset_id")
     * })
     */
    private $asset;

    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\Actag
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Actag")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="tag_id")
     * })
     */
    private $tag;



/**
 * Acasset
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acAsset", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_3B81679E68BA92E1", columns={"asset_type"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_3B81679E12469DE2", columns={"category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\AcAssetRepository")
 */
class Acasset
{      
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="asset_name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $assetName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="asset_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $assetId;

    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\Acassettype
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Acassettype", mappedBy="asset", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="asset_type_id", referencedColumnName="asset_type_id")
     * })
     */
    private $assetType;   


    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\Actag
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Actag")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="tag_id")
     * })
     */
    private $assetTags;

    /**
     * Set tag
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Actag $tag
     *
     * @return Acassettag
     */

    public function setAssetTags(\AdminBundle\Entity\Actag $tag = null)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return \AdminBundle\Entity\Actag
     */
    public function getAssetTags()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }
```

So in my Acasset entity I have created $assetTags but I am getting an error: Invalid column name 'tag_id'.

But $tag in the Acasettag entity works, which is set up the same way. What am I missing, still struggling a little with this part of Symfony.

I didnt't include all the getters and setters in this post, just the one I created for this.

Comment: Did you do it manually ?

Comment: I added assetTags manually, yes.

Comment: why not using dedicated commands ? (e.i. bin/console make:entity)

Comment: The entity already exists, I just want to add to it. So I guess I don't know, I've only ever used vanilla php.

Comment: make:entity allows you to modify entities as well. You can add a relation property between your entities then. Basically, create all your classes and then edit them to add the relations, quick & easy with make:entity command

Answer (score 0):

Why does your `Actag`-Entity hat also a `tagId` field? You don't need a defined Id-Column on the Owning-Side. You have to define a OneToMany.

Many `Acassettag` are owned by one `Actag` (because of the ManyToOne-Definition in `Acassettag`

So every `Acassettag` will need the field `actag_id` with the Id of the owning `Actag` which will be autogenerated by your `ManyToOne`-Definition

When you create a new `Acassettag` Entity and want to "connect" it with a existing `Actag` you need `Acassettag`

```
public setActag(Actag $actag)
{
    $this->tag = $actag;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: In addition, you can a OneToMany-Relation in your `Actag` to get all added `Acassettag`-Entities.